# Como llevar un variable javascript a otra pagina. ASP NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

Muy buenas, necesito su ayuda para saber si esto es posible.

Tengo una función que obtiene el id de un elemento y lo pasa a la variable img, luego redirecciona.

```
                function Redirect(element) {
                   var img = element.id
                  //redireccionar
```

}

¿Como puedo usar esa variable en la pagina al que me lleva?, ¿o que sugieren?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas formas. Una puede ser almacenando el valor en una `cookies`, otra puede ser a través del `url` del re direccionamiento, anexo un ejemplo de como hacerlo.

```
//Ejemplo de pasar una variable como parámetro a través del URL
function Redirect(element) {
 location.href = "www.example.com/html/redirect?img=" + encodeURI(element.id);
}
```

Luego en la pagina a donde se es redireccionado podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
function onload(){
 var value = location.href.match('[?&]img=([^&]+)'),
  img = value ? decodeURI(value[1]) : null;
  // Aqui lo que quieras hacer con el valor en "img"
  ..
  ..
}
```

Espero esto te sirva de ayuda ;))...

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me has salvado de un apuro y enseñado una nueva técnica con las url uwu

Comment: Me alegra saber que te ayudo, y recuerda calificar la respuesta que mas se adecue a la solución del problema, Saludos!!.